# Index Out of Range error when Huffman Coding

Tags: c#, image-processing, huffman-code, huffman-tree

I was trying to encode and decode an image using Huffman codes. I am encountering an issue when calling the methods from this class in the main method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public static class VLHuffman
{
    public static byte[] ConvertToByteArray(List<bool> boolList)
    {
        int numBytes = (boolList.Count + 7) / 8;
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[numBytes];
        for (int i = 0; i < boolList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (boolList[i])
            {
                byteArray[i / 8] |= (byte)(1 << (7 - i % 8));
            }
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
    private const int END_OF_FILE = -1;
    private const int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 256;
    private static int numAlphabets = 256;
    private static int numActive = 0;
    private static int[] frequency;
    private static uint originalSize = 0;
    private static List<Node> nodes;
    private static int numNodes = 0;
    private static int[] leafIndex;
    private static int[] parentIndex;
    private static int freeIndex = 1;
    private static int[] stack;
    private static int stackTop;
    private static byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    private static int bitsInBuffer = 0;
    private static int currentBit = 0;
    private static bool eofInput = false;
    public static List<bool> Compress(Bitmap inputImage)
    {
        List<int> pixelValues = GetImagePixelValues(inputImage);
        DetermineFrequency(pixelValues);
        stack = new int[numActive - 1];
        AllocateTree();
        AddLeaves();
        BuildTree();
        List<bool> compressedData = new List<bool>();
        EncodeHeader(compressedData);
        foreach (int pixelValue in pixelValues)
        {
            EncodeAlphabet(compressedData, pixelValue);
        }
        FlushBuffer(compressedData);
        return compressedData;
    }

    public static Bitmap Decompress(List<bool> compressedData, int width, int height)
    {
        ReadHeader(compressedData);
        BuildTree();
        List<int> decompressedPixelValues = DecodeBitStream(compressedData);
        return GetImageFromPixelValues(decompressedPixelValues, width, height);
    }

    private static void DetermineFrequency(List<int> pixelValues)
    {
        frequency = new int[2 * numAlphabets];
        leafIndex = new int[numAlphabets - 1];
        foreach (int pixelValue in pixelValues)
        {
            ++frequency[pixelValue];
            ++originalSize;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numAlphabets; ++i)
        {
            if (frequency[i] > 0)
                ++numActive;
        }
    }
    private static void AllocateTree()
    {
        nodes = new List<Node>(2 * numActive);
        parentIndex = new int[numActive];
    }
    private static int AddNode(int index, int weight)
    {
        int i = numNodes++;
        while (i > 0 && nodes[i - 1].Weight > weight)
        {
            nodes[i] = nodes[i - 1];
            if (nodes[i].Index < 0)
                ++leafIndex[-nodes[i].Index];
            else
                ++parentIndex[nodes[i].Index];
            --i;
        }

        nodes[i] = new Node(index, (uint)weight);
        if (index < 0)
            leafIndex[-index] = i;
        else
            parentIndex[index] = i;

        return i;
    }
    private static void AddLeaves()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numAlphabets; ++i)
        {
            int freq = frequency[i];
            if (freq > 0)
                AddNode(-(i + 1), freq);
        }
    }
    private static void BuildTree()
    {
        int a, b, index;
        while (freeIndex < numNodes)
        {
            a = freeIndex++;
            b = freeIndex++;
            index = AddNode(b / 2, (int)(nodes[a].Weight + nodes[b].Weight));
            parentIndex[b / 2] = index;
        }
    }
    private static List<int> DecodeBitStream(List<bool> compressedData)
    {
        int i = 0, bit, nodeIndex = nodes[numNodes].Index;
        List<int> decompressedPixelValues = new List<int>();
        while (true)
        {
            bit = ReadBit(compressedData);
            if (bit == -1)
                break;
            nodeIndex = nodes[nodeIndex * 2 - bit].Index;
            if (nodeIndex < 0)
            {
                int pixelValue = -nodeIndex - 1;
                decompressedPixelValues.Add(pixelValue);
                if (++i == originalSize)
                    break;
                nodeIndex = nodes[numNodes].Index;
            }
        }
        return decompressedPixelValues;
    }
    private static void EncodeAlphabet(List<bool> compressedData, int character)
    {
        int nodeIndex;
        stackTop = 0;
        nodeIndex = leafIndex[character + 1];
        while (nodeIndex < numNodes)
        {
            stack[stackTop++] = nodeIndex % 2;
            nodeIndex = parentIndex[(nodeIndex + 1) / 2];
        }
        while (--stackTop > -1)
            WriteBit(compressedData, stack[stackTop]);
    }
    private static void EncodeHeader(List<bool> compressedData)
    {
        byte[] headerBytes = WriteHeader();
        foreach (byte headerByte in headerBytes)
        {
            for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                int bit = (headerByte >> i) & 0x01;
                compressedData.Add(bit == 1);
            }
        }
    }
    private static byte[] WriteHeader()
    {
        List<byte> headerBytes = new List<byte>();
        int byteCount = sizeof(uint) + 1 + numActive * (1 + sizeof(int));
        headerBytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(originalSize));
        headerBytes.Add((byte)numActive);
        for (int i = 1; i <= numActive; ++i)
        {
            headerBytes.Add((byte)(-nodes[i].Index - 1));

            byte[] weightBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(nodes[i].Weight);
            headerBytes.AddRange(weightBytes);
        }
        return headerBytes.ToArray();
    }
    private static void ReadHeader(List<bool> compressedData)
    {
        byte[] headerBytes = ReadBytes(compressedData, sizeof(uint) + 1 + numActive * (1 + sizeof(int)));
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(headerBytes))
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            originalSize = reader.ReadUInt32();
            numActive = reader.ReadByte();
            AllocateTree(); // Corrected method name
            byte[] buffer = ReadBytes(compressedData, numActive * (1 + sizeof(int)));
            int byteIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= numActive; ++i)
            {
                nodes[i].Index = -(buffer[byteIndex++] + 1);
                nodes[i].Weight = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, byteIndex);
                byteIndex += sizeof(int);
            }
            numNodes = numActive;
        }
    }
    private static byte[] ReadBytes(List<bool> compressedData, int count)
    {
        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 8)
        {
            byte currentByte = 0;
            for (int j = 7; j >= 0; --j)
            {
                int bit = ReadBit(compressedData);
                currentByte |= (byte)(bit << j);
            }
            bytes.Add(currentByte);
        }
        return bytes.ToArray();
    }
    private static int ReadBit(List<bool> compressedData)
    {
        if (currentBit == bitsInBuffer)
        {
            if (eofInput)
                return END_OF_FILE;
            else
            {
                int bytesToRead = Math.Min(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, compressedData.Count - bitsInBuffer / 8);
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesToRead; ++i)
                {
                    buffer[i] = Convert.ToByte(compressedData[bitsInBuffer / 8 + i]);
                }

                bitsInBuffer = bytesToRead * 8;
                currentBit = 0;
                if (bitsInBuffer == 0)
                    return END_OF_FILE;
            }
        }
        int bit = (buffer[currentBit / 8] >> (7 - currentBit % 8)) & 0x01;
        ++currentBit;
        return bit;
    }
    private static void WriteBit(List<bool> compressedData, int bit)
    {
        if (bitsInBuffer == MAX_BUFFER_SIZE << 3)
        {
            foreach (var byteValue in buffer.Take(bitsInBuffer / 8))
            {
                for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    bool boolValue = ((byteValue >> i) & 0x01) == 1;
                    compressedData.Add(boolValue);
                }
            }
            bitsInBuffer = 0;
        }
        if (bit == 1)
            buffer[bitsInBuffer / 8] |= (byte)(0x1 << (7 - bitsInBuffer % 8));

        ++bitsInBuffer;
    }
    private static void FlushBuffer(List<bool> compressedData)
    {
        if (bitsInBuffer > 0)
        {
            foreach (var byteValue in buffer.Take((bitsInBuffer + 7) / 8))
            {
                for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    bool boolValue = ((byteValue >> i) & 0x01) == 1;
                    compressedData.Add(boolValue);
                }
            }
            bitsInBuffer = 0;
        }
    }
    private static List<int> GetImagePixelValues(Bitmap inputImage)
    {
        List<int> pixelValues = new List<int>();
        for (int y = 0; y < inputImage.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < inputImage.Width; x++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = inputImage.GetPixel(x, y);
                int grayscaleValue = (int)(pixelColor.R * 0.3 + pixelColor.G * 0.59 + pixelColor.B * 0.11);
                pixelValues.Add(grayscaleValue);
            }
        }
        return pixelValues;
    }
    private static Bitmap GetImageFromPixelValues(List<int> pixelValues, int width, int height)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Expected pixel values count: {width * height}");
        Bitmap decompressedImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream))
            {
                foreach (int pixelValue in pixelValues)
                {
                    binaryWriter.Write((byte)pixelValue);
                }
            }
            stream.Position = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    int pixelValue = stream.ReadByte();
                    Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(pixelValue, pixelValue, pixelValue);
                    decompressedImage.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
                }
            }
        }
        return decompressedImage;
    }
    private class Node : IComparable<Node>
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public uint Weight { get; set; }
        public Node(int index, uint weight)
        {
            Index = index;
            Weight = weight;
        }
        public int CompareTo(Node other)
        {
            return Weight.CompareTo(other.Weight);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried at least five different methods of going at Huffman coding. But every time, I am getting an error saying:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Item(Int32 index, T value)
   at VLHuffman.AddNode(Int32 index, Int32 weight) in VLHuffman.cs:line 98
   at VLHuffman.AddLeaves() in VLHuffman.cs:line 112
   at VLHuffman.Compress(Bitmap inputImage) in VLHuffman.cs:line 45
   at Program.Main() in Program.cs:line 60
```

I tried explicitly casting, that didn't work. Somewhere the conversion isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace gives a hint towards the offending statement: `nodes[i] = new Node(index, (uint)weight);` throws an IndexOutOfRangeException because it is trying to access a list item that doesn't exist.
While early on the nodes-List is initialized with an apropriate capacity, at no point any items are added.
The way the code is written I suppose using an array instead of a list will solve the issue right away (just like leafIndex and parentIndex are just arrays).